# Python -GTTS-Twilio - text message mp3

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, text-to-speech

I am attempting to use gtts to generate an audio file of text I am passing in as a variable ( eventually I will be scraping the text to be read, but not in this script, that is why I am using a variable) and I want to text myself the .mp3 file I am generating. It is not working though - here is my code. Any idea how to text message an .mp3 file with twilio?

```
    import twilio
from gtts import gTTS
from twilio.rest import Client
accountSID = '********'
authToken = '****************'
twilioCli = Client(accountSID, authToken)
myTwilioNumber = '*******'
myCellPhone = '*****'
v = 'test'

#add voice
tts = gTTS(v)
y = tts.save('hello.mp3')
message = twilioCli.messages.create(body = y, from_=myTwilioNumber, to=myCellPhone)
```

this is the error i get, but the link it directs me to does not speak to texting mp3 audio files:

```
     raise self.exception(method, uri, response, 'Unable to create record')
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: 
[31m[49mHTTP Error[0m [37m[49mYour request was:[0m

[36m[49mPOST /Accounts/********/Messages.json[0m

[37m[49mTwilio returned the following information:[0m

[34m[49mUnable to create record: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/********/Messages.json was not found[0m

[37m[49mMore information may be available here:[0m

[34m[49mhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404[0m
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't send an mp3 file as the body of a text message. If you do send a body, it should be a string.

You can deliver mp3 files as media messages in the US and Canada. In this case you need to make the mp3 file available at a URL. Then you set that URL as the `media_url` for the message, like this:

```
message = twilioCli.messages.create(
  from_=myTwilioNumber,
  to=myCellPhone,
  media_url="http://example.com/hello.mp3"
)
```

I recommend reading through the [documentation on sending media via MMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages?code-sample=code-send-an-mms-message&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x) and [what happens to MIME types like mp3 in MMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types#accepted-mime-types).